# asciiEncoding.GetString() in PHP?

Tags: c#, php

This is written in C#

```
ASCIIEncoding asciiEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] something= new byte[checked (buffer.Length - 1 + 1)];
str = asciiEncoding.GetString(something);
```

I am trying to find a function in PHP that does the same thing as `asciiEncoding.GetString()`

Is there any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asciiEncoding.GetString` will decode a byte array into a string. In PHP it could look like this:

```
$byteArray = unpack('C*', 'Some string');
$str = implode(array_map('chr', $byteArray));
```